# Instagram - Send a Direct Message to User

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We are building an Instagram Implementation in our application and we want to send a Direct Message (Inbox) with a code to which they have to enter in the app to verify the account.

I tried to check their API but was not able to get any information on the same.